# How to avoid the <div> and <ul> which added when custon menu widget is used

Tags: menus, widgets, navigation

I need to remove the custom menu widget

```
<div class="menu-main-container">
<ul id="main" class="menu">
```

from appearing above the `<li>`. Because of this two lines my menus are not appearing correctly as I given. I need to display the `<li>` menu list just after `<ul class="my_custom_class">` but now the above lines are appearing in between the my_custom class and `<li>` list.

If my explanation is not clear please forgive me & ask me for any further clarifications.

source code:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Top Menu',
    'id' => 'topmenu-sidebar',
    'description' => 'Appears as the sidebar on the all pages',
    'before_widget' => '<ul class="my_custom_class">',
    'after_widget' => '</ul>',
    'before_title' => '<li>',
    'after_title' => '</li>',
    ));
```

output:

```
<ul class="my_custom_class">
 <div class="menu-main-container">
   <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
      <li>....</li>
```

i need the output like below:[how i remove that div and ul. this is my issue]

```
<ul class="my_custom_class">
   <li>....</li>
```

**the above question is resolved.**

Comment: It commonly adding up from your `functions.php` under `register_sidebar()` function. Can you check there for necessary modification?

Comment: but sir..at there i gave <ul class="my_custom_class"> for before widget parameter.

Comment: If you have added before widget parameter, then it will wrap the content within that keeping the actual custom widget output. Can you please look into the source code and see the structure and confirm whether I am correct or not?

Comment: @Chittaranjan: please look at my updated question

Comment: ___Why___ do you need that particular structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the `div` and `ul` is the custom menu uses `wp_nav_menu` which generates the output. There are 2 arguments ( container, menu_class ) which have default values as `div` and `menu` respectively. As a result the output you see has a `div` and `ul` having class `menu`. Please have a look here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

The default custom menu does not provide any hook so that we can alter the output on the fly. So we have to create a similar widget which will allow us to manage the output. Please put the following code in your active theme's functions.php file

```
/**
 * WTI Custom Navigation Menu widget class
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */

class Wti_Custom_Nav_Menu_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'description' => __('Use this widget to add one of your custom menus as a widget.') );
        parent::__construct( 'custom_nav_menu', __('WTI Custom Menu'), $widget_ops );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        // Get menu
        $nav_menu = ! empty( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] ) : false;

        if ( !$nav_menu )
            return;

        $instance['title'] = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];

        wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'fallback_cb' => '',
                    'container' => '',
                    'menu_class' => $instance['menu_class'],
                    'menu' => $nav_menu
                )
            );

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags ( stripslashes ( $new_instance['title'] ) );
        $instance['menu_class'] = strip_tags ( stripslashes ( trim ( $new_instance['menu_class'] ) ) );
        $instance['nav_menu'] = (int) $new_instance['nav_menu'];

        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $menu_class = isset( $instance['menu_class'] ) ? $instance['menu_class'] : '';
        $nav_menu = isset( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? $instance['nav_menu'] : '';

        // Get menus
        $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

        // If no menus exists, direct the user to go and create some.
        if ( !$menus ) {
            echo '<p>'. sprintf( __('No menus have been created yet. <a href="%s">Create some</a>.'), admin_url('nav-menus.php') ) .'</p>';
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('menu_class'); ?>"><?php _e('Menu Class:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('menu_class'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('menu_class'); ?>" value="<?php echo $menu_class; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>"><?php _e('Select Menu:'); ?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nav_menu'); ?>">
        <?php
            foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $menu->term_id . '"'
                    . selected( $nav_menu, $menu->term_id, false )
                    . '>'. $menu->name . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}

function wti_custom_nav_menu_widget() {
    register_widget('Wti_Custom_Nav_Menu_Widget');
}

add_action ( 'widgets_init', 'wti_custom_nav_menu_widget', 1 );
```

Now you will see a new widget `WTI Custom Menu` on the widgets screen. Use this widget. This will have a field `menu_class` so that you can set the `class` of the `ul`. You can put whatever class you want like `my_custom_class` and save the widget. Now when you will see the output, this will not have any `div` which was earlier automatically generated and the `ul` will have a new class as you have set.

You will have to change `register_sidebar` code. Now no need to have `my_custom_class` as the widget will automatically generate this. You can have different html element like `div` for this.

Comment: wow..thats amazing... thank u..friend... but can i ask u one thing.. i upadated my code as like u said but when i give sub menu item it is not coming as drop down menu even if i wrote css code for that. can u please help me in that too??

Comment: the class i wrote in the css is "dropdown-menu" but now when i give a sub menu the class genberated is "sub-menu" and it displays just below the parent menu. why this happening like this? :( please help me

Comment: You need to define the css for the same class as you have assigned to the menu. Wordpress has built-in functionality for dropdown menu. So you can copy the code and modify it as per your structure and it should work.

Comment: u mean overwriting  "Walker_Nav_Menu"? i did that and the code is appended with my question. could u plz check it?because it is not working properly

Comment: I do not understand why you are going for walker class. Are you trying to modify the above code which I have provided?

You need to define the `css/js` for the above menu. Please refer to wordpress default theme where you will find the dropdown functionality already integrated. You can get the coding from there.

Comment: i'm sorry to bother u Chittaranjan.. i used that code because i'm using twitter bootstrap in my responsive theme.

Comment: My first answer was completely based on your actual question and you had accepted that. Now you are modifying the same question to include another. I would like you to keep the actual question and put the later added one as a completely new question.

Comment: i deleted that already friend...